# Why is this shuffling algorithm wrong?

Tags: algorithm, random, shuffle

Before I read about Fisher-Yates, this is the algorithm I came up with:

```
def sort(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        swap(arr, i, rand.randint(0, len(arr) - 1))
```

From my understanding, the only difference between this and Fisher-Yates is that instead of:

```
swap(arr, i, rand.randint(0, len(arr) - 1))
```

I should write:

```
swap(arr, i, rand.randint(i, len(arr) - 1))
```

Could someone explain how the first algorithm is incorrect? (ie. does not produce a random shuffle).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> Similarly, always selecting j from the entire range of valid array indices on every iteration also produces a result which is biased, albeit less obviously so. This can be seen from the fact that doing so yields n<sup>n</sup> distinct possible sequences of swaps, whereas there are only n! possible permutations of an n-element array. Since n<sup>n</sup> can never be evenly divisible by n! when n > 2 (as the latter is divisible by n−1, which shares no prime factors with n), some permutations must be produced by more of the n<sup>n</sup> sequences of swaps than others. As a concrete example of this bias, observe the distribution of possible outcomes of shuffling a three-element array [1, 2, 3]. There are 6 possible permutations of this array (3! = 6), but the algorithm produces 27 possible shuffles (3<sup>3</sup> = 27). In this case, [1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2], and [3, 2, 1] each result from 4 of the 27 shuffles, while each of the remaining 3 permutations occurs in 5 of the 27 shuffles.

Essentially, you are introducing a subtle bias into the shuffle, which will cause some permutations to crop up a bit more often than others. It's often not very noticeable, but it could make some sensitive applications (e.g. Monte Carlo simulations on permutations) fail to produce accurate answers.